# Route not defined even I defined it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Hey I am working on a code in which when user clicks update button it will go to another page that is doctorEdit. I defined the route in my web file but its again and again giving error route not defined. Can anyone please help me to reslove my problem. Below is my code.

Route code:

```
 Route::resource('doctor/doctorEdit','DoctorController@edit');
```

Controller code

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

   class DoctorController extends Controller
      {
     public function edit()
      {
    return view('doctor.doctorEdit');
      }
    }
```

And my view code is

```
   <form class="row" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit = "return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <a href="{{ route('doctor/doctorEdit', ['id' => $doctor->id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                    Update
                    </a>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong because I am new at laravel.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try using GET method with a named route.

Your routefile

```
Route::get('doctor/doctorEdit','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');
```

Your view code

```
<form class="row" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit = "return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <a href="{{ route('doctor.edit', ['id' => $doctor->id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                    Update
                    </a>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Great, Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong, take a look at the documentation on [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers).

Basically if you define a resource with `Route::resource()` method, you must not specify the controller action, since the *Resource Controller* is expected to provide compatible REST methods.

So if you want to create a REST resource controller you must specify your route as:

`Route::resource('doctor', 'DoctorController')`;

so you have to specify just your controller class name.

Then in your controller you have to specify required methods:

```
class DoctorController extends Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {
        // GET yourapp.com/doctor -> typically return all doctors
    }

    public function create()
    {
        // GET yourapp.com/doctor/create -> typically show doctor creation form
    }

    public function show()
    {
       // GET yourapp.com/doctor/{doctor_id} -> show a single doctor
    }

    public function store() 
    {
      // POST yourapp.com/doctor -> create a new doctor
    }

    public function edit()
    {
      // GET yourapp.com/doctor/{doctor_id}/edit -> show edit form view
      return view('doctor.doctorEdit');
    }

    public function update()
    {
       // PUT|PATCH yourapp.com/doctor/{doctor_id} -> update a doctor
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
       // DELETE yourapp.com/doctor/{doctor_id} -> delete a doctor
    }

}
```

If you just want to expose the `edit` form without the REST logic use the `Request::get()` method:

`Request::get('doctor/doctorEdit', 'DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');`

If your are caching your routes remember to refresh them using the artisan command sequence

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

or more concisely just
`php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a resource. The correct way to do this is:

```
Route::resource('doctor','DoctorController');
```

The name for the DELETE method is `doctor.destroy`, and the controller method is `destroy`

Your view code should be

```
        <form class="row" method="POST" action="{{ route('doctor.delete') }}" onsubmit = "return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <a href="{{ route('doctor.edit', ['id' => $doctor->id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                Update
                </a>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                  Delete
                </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: You have a form to delete a doctor and a link to edit a doctor. The route for deleting a doctor is named `doctor.destroy` and the one for editing a doctor is `doctor.edit`.

Comment: Oh you're right, i didn't see the DELETE method inside the form, i'm removing the downvote when SO will let me do it, my mistake, sorry EDIT: i cannot undo the downvote unless you edit the question